# Avoid infinite loading spinner in vue js

Tags: vue.js

I have a preloader in Vue js but it's infinite, how could I fix it? I was thinking about doing something to hide the div that contains the preloader when the page is loaded using mounted(), but I am not sure what should I do exactly. I am working in the App.vue file.

**EDIT: Tried to add the class d-none when the component is mounted but that didn't work**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return{
      classes: '',
    }
  },
  mounted(){
    this.classes='d-none';
  }
});
```

```css
/* Loader */
#preloader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    display: table
}

.loader {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px
}


#preloader,
.contact-box,
.scroll-to-top {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
        <div id="preloader" v-bind:class="classes">
      <div class="row loader">
          <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif" alt="logo" width="220" height="110">
          <br><br>
          </div>
      </div>
    <h1>content</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean its infinite? I can't find any loops in your code

Comment: with loading loop i mean the spinner

Comment: A quick google: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html. You probablly have to set an object for your class: Initialize as classes: {'d-none': true), and on mounted do: this.classes = {'d-none': false). You could discard the whole class thing and use v-if or v-show for example

Comment: And your example is missing a comma after the data() block

Comment: you have done completely wrong , so there is many things need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way to do this task in vuejs is using a `v-if`.

e.g

```html
   <div v-if="!isLoaded" id="preloader">
      <div class="row loader">
          <img src="https://media2.giphy.com/media/3oEjI6SIIHBdRxXI40/giphy.gif" alt="logo" width="220" height="110">
          <br><br>
       </div>
   </div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return{
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
   this.$nextTick(q => {
      // Will be executed when the DOM is ready
      this.isLoaded = true;

      // UPD : you can use this instead for your tests ..
      // setTimeout(function () { this.isLoaded = true; }, 2000)
   })
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think you need nextTick and it should be this.isLoaded = true

Comment: now I can't see anything, idk if it's because the page is loading too fast for me too see or what

Comment: you can test that with your browser network tab (limit your speed) or just simply use a  setTimeout function to check if its working or not.
`setTimeout(function () {
                    this.isLoaded = true;
            }, 2000);`

Comment: @user3791775 using nextTick is safer. (i had some problems with mounted function on few projects) and thanks for Reminding the missing `this`